# How Can I Run Sequential Temp Tables & Final SELECT Query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm used to BigQuery where I can run temp tables with the 'WITH' clause and then join those temp tables with a final query. However, I am now using a Hive db via DataGrip where I cannot run sequential temp tables in one query execution. Instead, I have to highlight every temp table block (within one script) and execute then on to the next one, then on to the next one, ... which is very annoying.

Help w/two items:

1. Does anyone know how I can run sequential temp tables and then finally join them all with a final SELECT statement?
2. Also, i find that the temp tables are stored in my session and I need to delete them with a simple line of code which is not a thing in BigQuery (again annoying). Can anyone help how I can deal with this? Because sometimes the temp tables can change column names and I don't want to worry about deleting the previous temp table with old columns names.

Here is an example of code:

```
-- audience temp table  
    CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW aud AS (
   1 SELECT
        exp_luid
    FROM audience_manager.segments5_luid
    WHERE segment_version_id IN (627, 629)
    )

-- KVJ table
    CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW prod AS (
    SELECT
        station_callsign,
        exp_luid,
        ds,
        ad_start_ts_utc as ad_time,
        COUNT(ds) AS impressions
    FROM vizio_production.kantar_vizio_v4_new
    WHERE  product_id = 36325675
        AND ds BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20190430
        AND exp_luid IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    )



-- Join KVJ and audience data set
    CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW join_one AS (
    SELECT
        aud.exp_luid AS exp_luid,
        prod.station_callsign AS network,
        prod.ds AS ds,
        prod.ad_time AS ad_time,
        SUM(prod.impressions) AS impressions
    FROM aud
    INNER JOIN prod ON aud.exp_luid = prod.exp_luid
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    )


SELECT * FROM join_one
```

Final join from select statement 'join_one' without caching the temp tables and running the entire SQL script in one script execution.

Comment: Hive supports common table expressions (CTEs), which is a fancy way of saying that it supports `WITH` constructs.  It is not clear why you cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

The Hive documentation leads me to believe that this would work:

```
WITH aud AS (
SELECT
    exp_luid
FROM audience_manager.segments5_luid
WHERE segment_version_id IN (627, 629)
),


prod AS (
SELECT
    station_callsign,
    exp_luid,
    ds,
    ad_start_ts_utc as ad_time,
    COUNT(ds) AS impressions
FROM vizio_production.kantar_vizio_v4_new
WHERE  product_id = 36325675
    AND ds BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20190430
    AND exp_luid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
),


join_one AS (
SELECT
    aud.exp_luid AS exp_luid,
    prod.station_callsign AS network,
    prod.ds AS ds,
    prod.ad_time AS ad_time,
    SUM(prod.impressions) AS impressions
FROM aud
INNER JOIN prod ON aud.exp_luid = prod.exp_luid
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
)


SELECT * FROM join_one
```

I'm not really clear on why you need to expand this into CTEs when doing it as a single query is relatively compact:

```
  SELECT
    aud.exp_luid AS exp_luid,
    prod.station_callsign AS network,
    prod.ds AS ds,
    prod.ad_time AS ad_time,
    SUM(prod.impressions) AS impressions
  FROM 
    audience_manager.segments5_luid aud
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT
        station_callsign,
        exp_luid,
        ds,
        ad_start_ts_utc as ad_time,
        COUNT(ds) AS impressions
      FROM vizio_production.kantar_vizio_v4_new
      WHERE  product_id = 36325675
        AND ds BETWEEN 20190101 AND 20190430
        AND exp_luid IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ) prod 
    ON aud.exp_luid = prod.exp_luid
  WHERE aud.segment_version_id IN (627, 629) 
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```